# Hypothesis testing multiple proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, proportion

Need help on my research!

1. We are introducing a new process in 2021 which might affect customer returns behavior. My data is in proportions which is total number of returns of total number of units sold. I need to test if there's a significant difference of returns/units sold in 2020 versus 2021 using the new process. Sample table below

[image]

****Question, given this data is it true that I can use the Z-test Hypothesis testing comparing two proportions?****

2. In relation to question no. 1, what if Total Business is breakdown into different categories. LIke the table below. Basically this is just a breakdown of the total business.

The objective is to test if there are significant difference in 2021 with new process in terms of category level.

[image]

**Given this, is it safe to use the CHI-SQUARE TEST?**

Comment: What are your sample sizes?

Comment: Percentages without sample sizes are not worth much: If you're comparing 50 vs. 60 successes in 1000 trials, then there is no significant difference (P-value =0.34); if you're comparing 500 vs. 600 successes in 10,000 trials, then the difference is highly significant (P-value =  0.0021).

Comment: Dear @AdrianKeister and BruceET, thank you for your response. I have updated my table above. Hoping you could check again. Thank you!

Comment: Basically I wanted to know what kind of test statistic to use.

Comment: How do you wind up with a non-integer number of units sold?

Comment: @Dave thanks for pointing out.. it should be a whole number. I have  updated the table

Answer (score 1):

A chi-square or (stratified-)Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel test could be an option, but it would only test whether the proportion are the same. That's a bit of a limitation. Presumably you also care about a few other things:

- How much of a difference is there? Some differences might matter a lot, very small ones less so (one could even look at the cost trade-offs)?
- What drives any difference? This might help you figure out whether it's more to do with the process or more about other factors. Given COVID-19 and everything else that changes in the world, looking at just to the top-line numbers could be very misleading. For example:

  - Consumers might have ordered more products they might have otherwise bought in a department store. That kind of customer might be more likely to return items, e.g. jewelry they could not see in person. Other items like, say, toilet paper are presumably a lot less likely to be returned.
  - New customers might be trying out ordering things for the first time and might be more or less likely to return things.

From those perspectives, I'd try to model at a high level of granularity. A basic model for that might be logistic regression. It might even be important to consider whether certain individual customers (in case you know which sales are for the same customers) are more likely to return items and which items are more likely to be returned (not just broad categories). Then, something like a random effects logistic regression could be an option. E.g. to use R code something like

```
library(lme4)

glmer(cbind(no_returned, no_sold-no_returned) ~ (1|customer_id) + (1|product_id) + product_category + process,
      binomial(link = "logit"))
```

would be a very simple model, but this is probably still too simplistic.

We still have to worry that the customers/situations under one process are different from those under another process (i.e. it's not a causal effect of the process, but rather about something else that is different with orders in one year vs. the other year).

So, if we truly wish to get at the causal effect of the process, we should consider causal inference techniques. E.g. one could use propensity scores for how representative orders are for one year vs. the other year (using all the possibly relevant information such as order history, transaction details etc. - in short anything you suspect might differ between the years - if you don't have all possible confounders, then that would be a limitation/a question mark on the conclusions), and adjust or stratify the analysis for these propensity scores. There's of course plenty of research ongoing on causal inference and you can make this [as sophisticated as you like](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02120).

Comment: Hi @Björn, thank you so much! Your input is well appreciated!